# Android Caching To Disk

Tags: java, android, caching, sharedpreferences

I am wondering if there is a way to cache arbitrary data from web requests onto the disk with Android. The flow I am thinking of is as follows:

The data is stored as a key value pair where the key is some identifier and the value is the raw data. Before actually making my web request, I check to see if the key is in the cache, if so, I skip making the web request. If the key does not exist in the cache, then I make the web request and store the data on the disk. I would like the cached data to be accessible across multiple runs of the app so that I don't have to make the web request again every time I start the app.

I was considering using `SharedPreferences` for this. Would `SharedPreferences` be the best way to go about this? Is it okay to store 1 megabyte of data in a single key in `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be coming late, but a couple years ago I made a library just for this:

https://github.com/fcopardo/EasyRest

The idea is to allow the app to operate with unstable or no connection without having to implement a secondary data layer for persisting data, instead, it keeps the responses for as long as you want, and refresh them without forcing the user to wait. Take a look, you may get some ideas.

Comment: I actually started using this library in my app and it is amazing! The author is a really nice guy and he showed me some examples of how to use it. He even made some PRs against my code base. https://github.com/Patchett/CryptoBuddy/pull/1/files

This library is extremely powerful, and you can tell it was written by a pro. I would highly recommend it. It improved the speed and performance of my app tremendously.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to storing cache files is to store them in a cache directory. Luckily, the Android API provides a solution to this problem: [`Context#getCacheDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()). You are able to create files in the directory returned, you can use a map to store an identifier for each file in order to retrieve them.

Although, this solution has a few limitations:

> The system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device.

Cache data should only be used for temporary storage of information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is very helpful. Given the limitation here, do you think it might be wiser to store this stuff in sqlite?

Comment: I think in your case, this approach would be viable. The removal of cache files only occurs when the user's device is low on storage. It also seems that you are able to re-fetch the data from a webservice if it is deleted. In most cases, the cache files should remain untouched.